# How to save my SQL codes in the SQL workbench/J in every session whenever I connect it to Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I'm documenting the code I write on SQL workbench/J while using Redshift, but it looks like the code is not saved automatically and I haven't been able to find any settings that would help me. Is there a way to save my SQL code and are there any commands that I need to run at the end of each connection session?

I have tried the following:
1. Went through all the connection settings and used "autocommit" to save the tables I create, but it doesn't save the code
2. Tried renaming the "Statement" tabs and doing Ctrl+S

I don't have prior experience with an SQL editor. I am asking this question in the coding section because I believe there must be a query that we can run to save the entire code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "save the entire code"? SQL Workbench stores everything from the editor tabs in the workspace assigned to your connection profile.

Comment: By saving the entire code, I am referring to the sql commands and queries I write on the "Statement" tabs/Editor tabs. In my case, the workbench does not save them automatically. When you put it that way, do you think this could be a problem with my software or a particular setting that I am missing like an option in the connection profile that I did not tick?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "save". Do you run a statement, but the changes aren't applied to the database? Or do you lose the text in the editor when you restart the tool?

Comment: I lose the text in the editor when I restart the tool or restart the connection.

Comment: As a horse already said, the contents of all editor tabs should be saved in the workspace associated with your connection profile. Is maybe the directory where that is stored not writeable? Is the workspace written/created at all?

Comment: Do you have "Autosave workspace" checked in your settings? It's under "Workspace"

Comment: @mdem7: that is for saving the workspace every time you run a query. The workspace is always saved when the application is properly close - that option is bascially a "fail-safe" for situations when the applications is killed.

Comment: got it, thanks for the clarification